# Safe Call From a thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have my main form, where I can call a `NuevoPago` which is a form and this new form has these Global vars:

```
Public Class NuevoPago
Dim Usuario As Usuario = Main.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Tag
```

But when I'm opening this form from a thread, it causes an error. It looks like I can access the `listview` control from the thread, but my question is how do I call the form in order to be able to access the controls if it's on a thread? Which control should I invoke, the main one or the new one? Should I use delegates?

I am using a simple call:

```
nuevopago.show()
```

Comment: 'it causes an error' What kind of error and what is the error message?

Comment: Your Main form is in running thread which is unavailable to newly created thread(s). Try passing the list view or main form as required to form NuevoPago.

Comment: As written, this code is *always* going to crash.  Displaying UI on a worker thread is the wrong thing to do in 99% of all cases.  The UI thread is already very capable of displaying any number of windows.  You completely omitted the *reason* why you think you needed to do this.  Just don't do it.  Use a BackgroundWorker to do what you want this form to do.